# Is the following a valid proof in number theory?

Tags: solution-verification

Prove the following using fundamental definitions.

> Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers such that $a|b$ and $a|c$. Then for any integer $k$, $ka + 3b ≡ c \mod a)$

What I've done:

"We need to show $ka + 3b ≡ c(mod a)$. So by the definition of congruent we need to show $ka + 3b - c = am$ with $m$ being an integer. So, we need to show $a|(ka + 3b -c)$.

Since $a|b$ then $a|3b$.
Since $a|c$ then $a|-c$.
Also, note $a|a$ so $a|ka$ for any integer $k$

Notice then that $a|(ka + 3b -c)$ since $a>0$

**Is this a valid proof?**

Comment: yes it works. $\ \ $

Comment: yes, it is a valid proof

Comment: Please use more specific titles.

Comment: My professor marked my proof incorrect so i was wondering if something did not make sense that i overlooked

Comment: @Maru, you can add that when $x|y$ and $x|z$, then $x|(y+z)$. also the word ```fundamental definitions.``` is a bit ambiguous, cuz it depends on your previous knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Notice that since $a\mid c$, $$c\equiv 0\pmod a.$$

Now, since $a\mid b$, then $$ka+3b\equiv 0\pmod a.$$

The claim follow.